# How to create a new ActiveRecord Connection Pool with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a RoR app that works great with the main RoR database. I also want to connect to arbitrary databases in a way such that I won't recreate the database connection with each new HTTP request.  From my research it looks like a connection pool is the way to go.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to create the pool itself:

```
config = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification.new( {
          "adapter"  => "postgresql",
          "host"     => "localhost",
          "port"     => 9000,
          "database" => "foo_test",
          "username" => "foo",
          "password" => "bar",
          "pool"     => "5",
          "timeout"  => "3000"
        })

my_connection_pool = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.new(config)
```

This errors with NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification.  Interstingly ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool works fine (but doesn't have the right config object).

What do I do here?

And also, are these the right things to be using to solve my problem?

Comment: Firstly: I don't really know... but I'd wonder where you got the code above and whether you have a rails-version mismatch... later versions of rails often do things like move or rename the class-structure.

Comment: I got the code from reading the documentation / AR code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/03edba1466114a3e1bd657b11164bb637a565fac/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

Comment: So... in the tags above, you specify Rails version 3, and the doco you have just linked-to is for Rails version 4.

Comment: Good point. I will see if that matters. I'm on Rails 3 right now.

Comment: Yep - I just checked... that class doesn't exist in Rails 3

Comment: you could upgrade? ;)

Comment: Upgrading is always nice to do, but connection pools and specifications definitely exist for Rails 3 too

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use case, Rails might do this for you automatically. Each `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass looks up the inheritance chain to find its pool, so

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Uses the `ActiveRecord::Base` connection pool, but

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection database: 'some_other_db'
end

class BarSub < Bar
end
```

would both connect to 'some_other_db' using the `Bar` pool.

I don't remember exactly, but I think every time you use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` (or `establish_connection` on any subclass) it creates a new pool. Doing otherwise would be absurd!

[A possibly helpful SO post on establish_connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191139/understanding-how-establish-connection-works-in-activerecord)

Comment: I will use this solution to modify the ConnectionPool class to set transaction isolation after initialization of the connection. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I just have a separate file in my initializers that i use to create multiple connection with. The lib file is :

```
require 'active_record'

module whateverName

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def base(dbName)
      establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[dbName.to_s][Rails.env])
    end
  end

end
```

Keep that file in lib and in models just include this and pass the database type. Make sure database.yml has the required configurations. Model will be something like :

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  include whateverName
  base :oracle
end
```

All you need to have is a config for oracle in database.yml.