# specify database adapter on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, pgcrypto

I'm using `pgcrypto` gem to encrypt data in certain columns of the database, but in order for this gem to work I have to specify `pgcrypto` as an adapter in `database.yml` file. I know that Heroku disregards this file and generates its own when application is pushed to Heroku server, which uses default `postgresql` adapter. Does anybody know if it's possible to override `adapter` value, with a configuration variable for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found the solution, which happened to be a quite simple one - I just had to replace the first token in the Heroku's database URL variable, so instead of

`postgres://username:password@host:port/dbname`

I use

`pgcrypto://username:password@host:port/dbname`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a database connection with

```
`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
```

you could also do this on a per-model basis using a mixing.

More info is here [Understanding how establish_connection works in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191139/understanding-how-establish-connection-works-in-activerecord)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I thought about that but really didn't want to have to specify all the connection properties for every model since I was only concerned about one particular setting - adapter.